# Yet Another Newbie to TypeScript error "TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined"

Tags: arrays, typescript

I think it is a problem with the creation of the transitions Array but I don't understand why !

the class text

```
export enum STATE_ID { CGU, Initial, Previous, Question}
export enum CHOICE_ID {CGU_accepted, CGU_not_accepted}

export class STATE_MACHINE {
    constructor (context: string) {
    this.transitions_initialize()
}   
put_transition (source: STATE_ID, target: STATE_ID, label: CHOICE_ID): void 
{console.log(this.transitions.length.toString)
    this.transitions[source][label] = target
}
private transitions: STATE_ID[][] = new Array()
private transitions_initialize(): void {
    this.put_transition(STATE_ID.Initial, STATE_ID.Question,                                            
                                                     CHOICE_ID.CGU_accepted)
    this.put_transition(STATE_ID.Initial, STATE_ID.CGU,           
                                                 CHOICE_ID.CGU_not_accepted)
    }
}
new STATE_MACHINE("test")
```

The error

```
[Function: toString]
Z:\Documents\Phi\Developpement\TypeScript\test3\state_machine.js:45
    this.transitions[source][label] = target;
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot set property '3' of undefined
    at STATE_MACHINE.put_transition (Z:\Docum................
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use a multidimensional array in TypeScript/JavaScript, you need to initialize each element.  When you do this:

```
private transitions: STATE_ID[][] = new Array()
```

You have created `transitions` as an *empty* array.  It contains no elements.  Each element should be of type `STATE_ID[]`.  If you want such an element to exist, you must create it first.  For example:

```
put_transition (source: STATE_ID, target: STATE_ID, label: CHOICE_ID): void {
  if (!this.transitions[source]) {
    this.transitions[source] = new Array()
  }
  this.transitions[source][label] = target
}
```

This should test for the condition that caused you a problem.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Great ! Thank you !